# Mass email in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm very new to programming so I am coming here for help. I am trying to make a simple mass emailer for fun, will not be using this at the moment, but sometime in the future I probably will at my IT job. My code does not seem to want to work for me.

```
import sys
import smtplib
emailfile = raw_input('Please enter the name of the text file that includes all email addresses: ')
emailtosendfrom = raw_input('Enter your email address to send from:  ')
msgfile = raw_input('Please enter the text file name that includes the message you want to send out  :')
email = open(emailfile, 'r')
toaddrs = email
msg = open(msgfile, 'r')


# Credentials
password = raw_input('Please enter your email password  :  ')

# Send mail
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(emailtosendfrom,password)
with open(emailfile) as f:
    emailsort = f.readlines()
    for user in emailsort:
        server.sendmail(emailtosendfrom, user, msg)
f.close()
server.quit()
```

This code returns the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mail.py", line 26, in <module>
    server.sendmail(emailtosendfrom, line, msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 717,
    esmtp_opts.append("size=%d" % len(msg))
TypeError: object of type 'file' has no len()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message should be a string, not a file. First get the message body by replacing:

```
msg = open(emailfile, 'r')
```

with:

```
with open(emailfile) as msg:
    msgbody = msg.read()
```

and then fix the loop itself with:

```
server.sendmail(emailtosendfrom, user, msgbody)
```

---

While not directly related to the question, here are my 2cents:

1. Use module [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) to ask user for a password, so that it will not be displayed on screen.
2. you are opening files but never closing them. In this case it's not a great issue, because the script will terminate few milliseconds after. In general, you should wrap everything in `with` blocks. Apart from closing the file handle, they will also make clear where the file is actually used.
3. some line are redundant, like `email = open(emailfile, 'r')` and `toaddrs = email`.

Finally, you can replace:

```
emailsort = f.readlines()
for user in emailsort:
```

with:

```
for user in f:
```

but be sure to strip the final `\n` (or the email addresses will be wrong).